# How to get URL of photo gallery in the user's phone?

Tags: android, photo-gallery, android-external-storage, android-internal-storage

I want to an OpenCV4Android method `imwrite()` to save an image in the photo gallery in the user's phone:

```
Highgui.imwrite(string_path_to_directory + "/file_name.jpg", actual_photo_file);
```

The first argument is the path to the User's photo gallery. I need that path.

For example, if I wanted to store the photo in the `DCIM` directory inside *external storage*, I'd have used `"/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/file_name.jpg"` as path.

Ideally, I'd like to create a new folder in the photos gallery and store the file in that folder (like Instagram does, when we capture or edit a photo in Instagram, a folder named `Instagram` is created in photos gallery and the photo captured or edited are stored there).

Comment: Not sure why you're using the `/mnt` folder... the full paths vary from phone to phone. As long as you don't need to support old Gingerbread phones, you're safest absolute path would be `/sdcard/DCIM`.